# Retrofit with custom JsonDeserializer in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin, retrofit

I need to parse this json. It works fine by default, but I need to add timestamp, so i use custom deserialize factory.

```
[
  {
"ccy": "USD",
"base_ccy": "UAH",
"buy": "26.60000",
"sale": "26.96000"
  },
  {
"ccy": "EUR",
"base_ccy": "UAH",
"buy": "28.95000",
"sale": "29.60000"
  },
  {
"ccy": "RUR",
"base_ccy": "UAH",
"buy": "0.35000",
"sale": "0.38500"
  },
  {
"ccy": "BTC",
"base_ccy": "USD",
"buy": "8610.8989",
"sale": "9517.3093"
 }
]
```

But  json: JsonElement? parametr in MyDeserializer never come with ArrayList, always in single object. How i can read remote json for ArrayList, аnd modify it?

```
 class MyDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<ArrayList<CurrencyItem>> {

    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement?,
        typeOfT: Type?,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): ArrayList<CurrencyItem> {

        //Clean array save result
        var currrencyList = ArrayList<CurrencyItem>()

        // Get remote json
        val itemsJsonArray = jsonObject.asJsonArray

       //Modify remote json to custom object with timestamp
        for (item in itemsJsonArray) {

            var JsonObject = item.asJsonObject

            var ccy = JsonObject.get("ccy").asString
            var base_ccy = JsonObject.get("base_ccy").asString
            var buy = JsonObject.get("buy").asString
            var sale = JsonObject.get("sale").asString

            var timestamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())

            currrencyList.add(CurrencyItem(1, ccy, base_ccy, buy, sale, time))

        }
        return currrencyList
    }


}
```

Add custom converter to retrofit

```
       //Add converter to retrofit
        val retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.privatbank.ua/")

            //My custom converter
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(customGson))

           .client(okkHttpclient)
           .build()
```

Comment: Did you added your deserializer as an adapter for your type (ArrayList<CurrencyItem>) to the gsonBuilder  ?
Retrofit won't know magically that it needs to use it if you dont tell it.

Comment: I added only factory  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(customGson))

Comment: How is that "customGson" created?

Comment: //Custom JSON
        val customGson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(CurrencyItem::class.java, MyDeserializer()).create()

Comment: Ok there's the problem, let me write a proper answer for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're registering your deserializer with the wrong type:

```
JsonDeserializer<ArrayList<CurrencyItem>>
```

The type for your deserializer is

```
ArrayList<CurrentItem>
```

Yet, you're registering it with

```
CurrencyItem::class.java
```

Now, registering generic types is not straightforward as plain types.
In your case you need:

```
Type currencyItemListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CurrencyItem>>() {}.getType();
registerTypeAdapter(currencyItemListType, MyDeserializer())code here
```

With that, when de retrofit call returns with a success code (2xx) it shoud automatically try to deserialize the json with your deserializer

Comment: if i register  val currencyItemListType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<CurrencyItem?>?>() {}.type //
val customGson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(currencyItemListType, MyDeserializer()).create() // JsonDeserializer work like  <ArrayList<CurrencyItem>>